# Cards don't fill row as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The code displays a navbar, side panel and the main panel where data is displayed.
I have a few nested rows and in the last nesting I want to display 3 cards that will fill the entire remaining width, but so far they are stuck to the left:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Sidebar + Main Panel</title>


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 mr-0 px-3" href="#">Sidebar + Main Panel</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
      <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
        <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem1
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                     SidebarItem2
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                     SidebarItem3
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem4
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem5
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem6
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">     
                                    SidebarItem7
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">     
                                   SidebarItem8
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">                                       SidebarItem9
                                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

      <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
        <div class="row" style="background:black;">
          <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">

            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm col-md-4">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>10 users included</li>
                  <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm col-md-4">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$15 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>20 users included</li>
                  <li>10 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Priority email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm col-md-4">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$29 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                  <li>30 users included</li>
                  <li>15 GB of storage</li>
                  <li>Phone and email support</li>
                  <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What I'm trying to do is to be able to add rows of 3 cards in the center of the Main panel space, but as you can see it is pushed to the left - I made a black background so you can see it better.
It should be viewed in a desktop mode not responsive

Comment: If you want to make the three card fill the entire width of the screen, add `w-100` class to the `.card-deck` division. **OR** if you want the cards to be center aligned, you can add `m-auto` class to `.card-deck` element.

Comment: One hint (which does not solve the problem): `div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3` is missing its closing tag

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the margin left and right to **auto** on the card deck class:

```
.card-deck {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I order to center the three cards in the row (styled with `background-color: black;` you need to add horizontal margin of the `div class="card-deck mx-auto mb-3"`

Horizontal margin `auto` in bootstrap -> `mx-auto`

Or with Vanilla CSS

```css
.card-deck {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

P.S. If `.card-deck` is unique on the page, then it should be id="card-deck"

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is add the class 'justify-content-center' in the parent row of 'card-deck' or add the style 'margin: 0 auto;' in the 'card-deck' class.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of issues in your code, especially with your sidebar. Since you did not request assistance for that I am ignoring it, but fix that at first because it is killing your design.

To center align your pricing table you can remove the row inside main and just use card-deck (ref: [Pricing table simple](https://jsfiddle.net/Grobbert/o2jqkd9m/2/)).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="css/sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Sidebar + Main Panel</title>


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top bg-dark flex-md-nowrap p-0 shadow">
    <a class="navbar-brand col-md-3 col-lg-2 mr-0 px-3" href="#">Sidebar + Main Panel</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler position-absolute d-md-none collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sidebarMenu" aria-controls="sidebarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

    <ul class="navbar-nav px-3">
      <li class="nav-item text-nowrap">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign out</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
        <div class="sidebar-sticky pt-3">
          <ul class="nav flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem1
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                     SidebarItem2
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                     SidebarItem3
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem4
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem5
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                    SidebarItem6
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">     
                                    SidebarItem7
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">     
                                   SidebarItem8
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">                                       SidebarItem9
                                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>

      <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4" style="background-color: #000">
        
        <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Free</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$0 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>5 users included</li>
                    <li>2 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Email support</li>
                    <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-primary">Sign up for free</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Pro</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$25 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>20 users included</li>
                    <li>10 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Priority email support</li>
                    <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Enterprise</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$99 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h1>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                    <li>illimited users included</li>
                    <li>50 GB of storage</li>
                    <li>Phone and email support</li>
                    <li>Help center access</li>
                </ul>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Contact us</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
          
      </main>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove div with card-deck class and leave only inner col-md-4 if you want fill the entire remaining width, otherwise if you want center your cards and leave background all around, simply add the style margin:0 auto to your .card-deck class.